# Flash AS3 Crossdomain bypass issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm currently hosting a flash game on my website which is https: .
I've added a crossdomain file that specifies I only allow access from this website that my flash application is hosted on. 
If I download the swf file and try to run it from my local computer, it wont let me (which is what I wanted), however, if i go to flash -> global settings -> Advanced -> trusted location settings , and add the file that I've downloaded to the trusted locations, It will ignore the crossdomain and let me play (which is not what I want).

here's my crossdomain policy file:

```
  $@"<cross-domain-policy>
        <allow-access-from domain=""{Domain}""/>
        <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies=""master-only""/>
        <allow-http-request-headers-from domain=""{Domain}"" headers=""*"" secure=""true""/>
        </cross-domain-policy>";
```

I would appreciate any kind of help :=)

Comment: That is how cross-domain security works. No one would be able to host your SWF online, but once Flash Player knows SWF is in trusted location, it will bypass security check. Your options are: a) relative URLs or b) URL-locking your SWF. Another layer of security you might want to add is code obfuscation (like SecureSWF tool) because these days you can view and edit scripts inside the compiled SWF, so a minor  trick won't stop someone who knows what to do.

Comment: I've already tried URL-Locking and obfuscating with "SWF Defender" but it seems that hackers find a way around it very easily. 

Appreciate the fast reply :=) Thanks!

Comment: I didn't work with Defender so I don't know how much of protection it provides. I don't know what your exact problem might be or full tech specs of your application, but there's a piece of info. The weak point might be the communication protocol. There are ways (like Charles Proxy) to intercept and change the outgoing/incoming traffic, it does not require downloading, or debugging or hacking your client app.

Comment: If it is the case, you need to sign your data packets so that signature would not match if any data was changed on the packet. This also requires some session-generated variables, timestamp and ever increasing packet index number. This way you would ensure that no packet would be exactly the same (getting the same packet twice will mean fraud), then it all will rely on the signing algorithm, which should be, obviously, heavily obfuscated as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll keep digging and see what I can come up with :=)