# How to detect if connecting client was modified (Server: C#, Client: AS3)

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

Sorry, tried looking for existing thread, lucked out.

Just curious if anyone has tactics to protect a vulnerable game client that basically all anyone has to do is use a flash decompiler to modify hacks into it. Does anyone know how I can upload the "legit" Flash client online and then people can ONLY connect to it by playing on the website its uploaded to, or by using the URL inside of flash projector? If they download the client and try to load it as a file then it rejects, i think its called a "domain lock" or something like that. Or if I can figure out a way for the client to be uploaded to my site, but IMPOSSIBLE to download off of it (like they cant just press CTRL+S and save the file to their desktop), that would be cool too.

Or if anyone has other suggestions involving hardcode to be placed into the C# server or the AS3 client.

Just please help if you can, most likely with that first part of the paragraph, that part seems like a solid plan, as long as they cant download the client, they cant modify it so then I wouldnt even have to care if they can connect or not.

Comment: Although that question is about another issue, I posted a couple of advises there that are totally relevant for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53751372/4687633

Comment: This isn't an easy task. You could be better assuming that your client IS modified, that is, verify any and every input from that client, and not give it more than you need to give, so that the player won't leverage excessive data even with a modified client. There are still things that a modified client would do better than an average player (namely auto aiming in a shooter, and other things available with a zero time reaction), which you pretty much must let through as this is *possible* with an unmodified client, so better use a different approach to filter such clients out server side.

Comment: Remember, ALL software and games can be hacked. The top games like Call of Duty have so many hackers you can find about 1 in a 1000 players hacking right now. Call of Duty can't stop hackers because there's no way to stop this type of hacking. You can only do some basic architecture so it's not easy to hack.

Comment: Easy way to accomplish that: Host the webpage in your local IIS or an external page. Edit your hosts file and say your IP is that domain. Browse that "external" website and your web browser will show your hosting controlled website. Do note that it was accomplish without no developing involved.

Answer (score 1):

You're focusing on the wrong problem.

You can do a number of things to make life difficult for someone trying to use an unauthorized client. You could, for example, embed a cryptographic one-time use token in the client that's good only for a given session and make the client encrypt any communication with the server with it- until the person designs a mod that downloads the client every time and extracts the token.

You can use javascript to try and make it non-trivial to download the client- until the user writes a Tampermonkey script that disables your protections.

Ultimately, if the code is running client-side there is literally nothing you can do to completely guarantee a determined actor won't be modifying it or even building their own client to connect to your servers. What you should be doing instead is working on your server code to detect actions that an unmodified client would never send. Treat all clients as untrustworthy and validate the data you're receiving from them. Assume your server is going to be receiving inputs that are *completely* unreasonable and handle edge cases accordingly. (Also, don't immediately assume the unreasonable inputs you receive are deliberate cheating- they could just as easily be the result of bugs in the client or even faulty hardware on the user's end.)

Comment: OP is the person trying to get into the services unauthorized. Check [this related question (same author)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974166/bypassing-a-domain-lock).

Comment: @bradbury9 sorry i wasnt able to say this in time before the other question got closed or whatever, i am clearly not as dedicated to this site as most of the people are. i should have remembered how arrogant and uptight the community was from my last account and how badly people take it to the heart when a question is asked by someone who isnt ask skilled nor experienced as them so obviously the question might lack detail or specifics, even when all they have to do is just ignore and keep scrolling... there are no such things as stupid questions but there are such things as stupid answers..

Comment: didnt fit enough characters to mention this part, if you look at the dates, this question was posted first, and the other question posted afterwards that you mentioned about "hacking into somebodies service" was about MY GAME. I was asking it from a 3rd person point of view to get answers and test them against my domain lock which is a solution i got from THIS QUESTION. (not exactly this question, but from the URL that someone left on this question)... so go ahead and be just like the other thousands of cocky stuck up so-called "helpful" developers on this site and just jump to assumptions.